# Google Contacts API for Organization Directory

Tags: gdata, google-contacts-api

I want to retrive all the contacts in my organization directory via API. I tried querying using [OAuth Playground](https://code.google.com/oauthplayground) but I didn't get any group for my "Directory". I want to fetch all the people in my organization.

[image: Google contacts]

Comment: Saw this API - http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/profiles/developers_guide.html#retrieving_without_query. Will post answer after trying it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested, and

```
http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/profiles/developers_gude.html#retrieving_without_query
```

works fine. Scope should be

```
 https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/profiles
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Is it because its deprecated? Found something similar here: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/domain-shared-contacts/. Works only with Admin accounts. When tried as a normal user it returned 403. Is there any API where a user accounts auth can retrieve the contacts listed under Directory?